# How to show a "possible" relationship in an algorithm running time function?

Tags: summation, algorithms, computer-science

I am working on generalizing the time complexity for a given algorithm by using mathematical notation. The idea is that the running time of an algorithm is the sum of running times of the statements of the algorithm.

Let $n$ be the input size

Let $T(n)$ be the running time of an algorithm

Let $s$ be the number of statements in the algorithm

Let $c$ be the cost of a statement measured by steps of the statement.

Let $t$ be the times that each statement has to execute dependent on $n$.

$T(n) = \sum_{s}(c_s*t_s)$

In order to successfully calculate $c$ or $t$ one must know the details about the algorithm in question.

For example, lets say we have an algorithm with the following statements:

1. A programmatic flag set to true(happens only once at the beginning of the algorithm)
2. Some **for** or **while** loop

We could say that $t_s$ when $s=1$ is constant and doesn't scale with the input size. When we move to statement 2(for loop) we could say that $t_s$ when $s=2$ does scale with the input size because $t_2 = n$(the for loop will execute n times).

How do we capture this relationship between $t$ and $n$ in mathematical notation without knowing the algorithm in question? Would $T(n) = \sum_{s}(c_s*t_s)$ be acceptable to capture the relationship?

Comment: A detail: you cannot write a sum on $s=1$ to $s$, i.e. $s$ cannot have two roles.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni I guess the idea here would be s is the number of statements, and we would start at s=1 and sum until we reach the length of s. I edited the sum

Comment: If you want to emphasize that $t$ depends on $n$ while $c$ does not, you could write it as $t(n)$.

Comment: @Karl so something like $T(n) = \sum_{s}(c_s*t(n)_s)$? I am struggling to understand if this makes sense or not because its possible that $t$ doesn’t have a relationship with $n$ depending on the statement of the algorithm in question.

Comment: If $s$ is the *number of steps*, then don't also use it as the *index of a step*. I'd write $\sum_{i=1}^sc_i t_i(n)$.

Comment: It's fine for a function to have the same value on all inputs. You can have $t_2(n)=n$ and $t_1(n)=1$. In this case, $t_1$ is a [constant function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_function).

Comment: @Karl I think that is what I was looking for! Thanks!